# Consumer preferences and government spending

Tags: macroeconomics, real-business-cycles

I am studying for an exam and I am focusing on different types of preferences and shocks and the respective responses. This problem has been causing me trouble.

The representative consumer in an economy has the lifetime utility function:

$U = \sum \beta^t U(c_t, l_t)$, where $c_t$ is consumption in period t and $l_t$ is labor supply and $U(c_t, l_t)= c_t^\frac{1}{2} - l_t$. The production technology is given by $y_t= A_t \times l_t$ where $y_t$ is output in period t. Consumers can lend and borrow freely at the interest rate $r_t$ and the government spending in period t, $g_t$ is exogeneously given and is financed by lump-sum taxes and government debt.

1) What is the intertemporal elasticity of substitution in consumption?

I know the IES is is the measure of responsiveness to the growth rate of consumption to the real interest rate.

2) Derive equilibrium levels of consumption, output, employment and interest rate in each period in terms of exogenous variables and given parameters in the model.

3) Discuss the effects of changes in government spending on consumption, output, employment and interest rate. Is there a crowding out effect of government spending in this economy?

4) Is it true that the level of government spending is irrelevant in this economy?

I think the answer to this is no intuitively.

5) Is it true that the distribution of government debt across time is irrelevant in this economy?

I think the answer to this is yes, it is true due to Ricardian equivalence.

Comment: That is a typo, thanks for catching that! I have edited the question to reflect that.